# Complete rules for the epenthetic л in verb conjugations

Tags: глаголы, спряжение

My question is twofold:

1. What are the complete and exact rules that govern the epenthetic л in verb conjugations i.e. the л that is inserted either just in the first person singular of certain –и conjugation verbs (such as любить – люблю) or throughout the conjugation of certain -e conjugation verbs (such as трепать – треплю, треплешь, треплет, треплем, треплете, треплют) ?
2. More importantly, what are the underlying phonological, etymological or historical rationales behind these rules ?

**Can someone please review my comments on the first answer and address the pending questions so that I can close this question and award the bounty. Thank you very much,**

Answer (score 1):

> What are the complete and exact rules that govern the epenthetic *л* in verb conjugations

It's inserted between a bilabial consonant (*b, p, m, f, v*) and *j* (except before *а*): *люблю, куплю, кормлю, графлю, ловлю*, but *любит, купит; любят, купят*.

> More importantly, what are the underlying phonological, etymological or historical rationales behind these rules ?

It's one of the manifestations of the [law of rising sonority](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%BA_%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B9_%D0%B7%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8). It's not confined to the verb endings: *земля < zemja, блюдо < biutta, Скопле < Skupi* are all examples.

Other manifestation of this law, very closely related to the epenthetic *l*, is the [iotation](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%99%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B2_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC_%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B5).

Comment: Thank you very much. Do I therefore understand correctly that an epenthetic л would appear between any of the five consonants б, п, м, ф, в and the following three vowels e, ё or ю (as я would be an exception, as you noted above).  

1) Is there any example with the letter ё?

2) And what about the sound “ji”: is there any example with such a sound/vowel (not sure I depicted the sound correctly though). 

3) Am I missing any other vowel other than the three aforementioned?

Comment: Why doesn’t the л appear in the conjugation of the verb убить (to kill – убью́, убьёшь, убьёт, убьём, убьёте, убью́т) ? Is it because of the soft sign ь or is it another rule? Is it the same for бить (to beat) ?

Comment: And why there is no л appearing in the conjugation of the verb успеть (to be on time – успе́ю, успе́ешь, успе́ет, успе́ем, успе́ете, успе́ют). Is it because the e after the п is stressed and hence the sound “je” becomes “e” ?

Comment: And why there is no л appearing in the conjugation of the verb звать after the ё (to call, to name – зовёшь, зовёт, зовём, зовёте) ?

Comment: And why there is no л appearing in the conjugation of the verb вызвать (to call, to send – вы́зовешь, вы́зовет, вы́зовем and вы́зовете) ?